# Searching a 2D array with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

For a homework assignment, we've been been told to write functions like sum, find_max, and find_min that operate on a 2D matrix. I'd use something like this to find the maximum value normally.

```
double find_max(double *the_array, int row_size, int col_size) {
    double maxValue = *the_array[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < col_size; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < row_size; j++) {
             if (*the_array[i][j] > maxValue) {
                  maxValue = *the_array[i][j];
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

However, we've been told to use pointers instead of arrays for this homework. I'm guessing that means I need to use pointer arithmetic to go through the array, but I'm not sure how to do that. What sort of loop do I use? How do I know when to tell it to stop?

Comment: "However, we've been told to use pointers instead of arrays for this homework." Your code is already using pointers, there are no arrays in your shown code. Also what is `double maxValue = *the_array[0][0]` supposed to do? O_o

Comment: To double dereference you need a double pointer as parameter `double **the_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this
Your the_array is really just linear memory of size row * col.

```
double find_max(double *the_array, int row_size, int col_size)
{
    double *iterator = the_array;
    double *end = the_array + row_size * col_size;
    double max = DBL_MIN;

    while (iterator < end) {
        if (*iterator > max)
            max = *iterator;

        ++iterator;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: I also took the liberty of fixing the initial value. What if the array contains negative numbers? Initialising `max` to `0` will give wrong results there. ...not that we should be encouraging code like this in C++, but homework doesn't tend to come up with interesting questions, instead of 'reinvent `<algorithm>`.' :(

Answer (score 0):

the_array should be a pointer of pointer on double.I mean that:
    `double find_max(double **the_array, int row_size, int col_size)`